# Django FormPreview with data from previous POST

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I want a scenario in which after submission Form is previed to confirm and I tried to use Django built-in FormPreview. Problem is that it forces scenario in which Form is rendered on FormPreview page, then after submision it is previed (with possibility to edit) and then it is actually send.

I would like to have something like this:

1. Form is submited from some page contaning a lot of other data (not only this Form, and possibly also other Forms)
2. The user see preview of their Form (wihout posibility to edit it now, just confirm or cancel, we can assume that form is valid on this part). Also there could be some more information on the Form based on user input (i.e. sum of some items)
3. Now user can submit this Form and it will be saved to DB

Could this be done with FormPreview or I would need to write the preview page manually? And if so what would be the best way to pass the data after preview, create hidden Form with all the data from previous POST?